# Swift 3: How to write Equatable func

Tags: swift3, equatable

I am trying to use struct as my key for dictionary.

Code works for `swift 2`, however not for `swift 3` as in the picture link.

**Equatable Code:**

[image: Equatable Code]

Comment: Please add the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: The code cannot work in Swift 2 either.  The error message is very clear: **Operators are only allowed at global scope**

Comment: @appzYourLife will do next time

Answer (score 4):

Any Swift type that conforms the Hashable protocol must also conform the Equatable protocol. Because Hashable protocol is inherited from Equatable protocol[(source)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/hashable). That's why you are getting that error message.

As for your question, == function must be declared globally since you are overriding global == operator to be able to compare two Attributes you defined. With Swift 3, you can also define == in the struct itself, but it has to be static.

```
struct Attributes: Hashable {
  var uid: Int
  var size: Size
  var mimeType: mimeType

  var hashValue: Int {
      return uid
  }

  static func ==(lhs: Attributes, rhs: Attributes) -> Bool {
      return lhs.size == rhs.size && lhs.mimeType == rhs.mimeType
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not about the Swift version. It will give error also on Swift 2. The problem is that you must define the `==` functions **outside** of the Struct because it must be a global function.

Comment: Thanks. First time working with Hashable, Equatable. Works nicely now.

Comment: @selcuk: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)